# Why does FCM's onMessage() need to be wrapped in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone explain the reason that FCM's `onMessage()` does not behave in a similar manner to Firestore's `onSnapshot()` or Auth's `onAuthStateChanged()`?

The latter two start up a “listener” that remains running and when data arrives each invokes their callback, and the listeners keep going until they are shutdown.  But it seems that to get `onMessage()` to run properly it needs to be re-invoked after each message is received, or possibly even more frequently?

Or maybe I’m just not properly understanding the reason that to be successful it seems  I need to wrap a call to onMessage in a Promise or an async IIFE:

```
(async () => {
    return onMessage(getMessaging(), (payload: MessagePayload) => {
        console.log(`App() - onMessage() - got payload:`, payload);
        setNotificationPayload([{ data: payload, open: true }]);
    });
})()
```

or a similar pattern I see in various tutorials/blogs is:

```
export const onMessageListener = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });
```

Where I am confused is that these calls are being put directly into components so that they re-run with every render of the component, whereas the other listeners in Firebase-land seem to be started, stopped and protected against re-execution by use of a `useEffect()`.

Or maybe I’m just massively confused right now...

Comment: The reason FCM is different from Firestore and Auth here is that in the latter two the listener runs in your process, while in the case of FCM the listener is actually part of the operating system/browser.

Comment: Thank you Puf.  This distinction does not "jump out at me" from reading the docs.  I had to go searching for working examples to understand why mine didn't....and this Promise/IIFE thing is the difference.